# What are the sorting order of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

**input1**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
data = {'item': np.random.choice(['skirt', 'shirt', 'coat'], 6),
        'size': np.random.choice(['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'], 6)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df1:

```
    item    size
0   skirt   S
1   shirt   XL
2   skirt   L
3   shirt   S
4   shirt   S
5   coat    S
```

when i sort by `size`

```
df1.sort_values('size')
```

out:

```
    item    size
2   skirt   L
0   skirt   S
3   shirt   S
4   shirt   S
5   coat    S
1   shirt   XL
```

The data is sorted by the `size` column, and when the values of the `size` column are the same, the rows that were originally higher remain higher.

---

**input2**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.max_rows = 6
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = {'item': np.random.choice(['skirt', 'shirt', 'coat'], 1000000),
        'size': np.random.choice(['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'], 1000000)}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df2

```
         item size
0       skirt    M
1       shirt    L
2       skirt    M
...       ...  ...
999997   coat    S
999998  shirt    S
999999  skirt    L

[1000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

df2 has 1M rows

when i sort by `size`

```
df2.sort_values('size')
```

out:

```
         item size
999999  skirt    L   <- why top?
645704  shirt    L
645714  shirt    L
...       ...  ...
822256   coat   XL
699230   coat   XL
400737  skirt   XL

[1000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

I don't know why `999999 row` is at the top in `df2`.

Shouldn't the existing order be followed if `size` is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a "stable" sort.  "Stable" means it maintains the current order when the keys are identical.  The default algorithm, quicksort, is not stable.

```
df2.sort_values('size',kind='stable')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you have any good documentation on quicksort, I would appreciate it if you could share it. I will also look for it.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles for "stable sort" and "quicksort" are both good, but such knowledge is not really relevant to your problem.  If you need a stable sort, then you ask for it.  Just that simple.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using stable is the way to go. However, I was curious why 999999 came first in quicksort, so I wanted to look into it. Anyway, thank you for your answer. good day.

Comment: It is pure coincidence.  Just a random artifact of the algorithm.